# Is there any predefined function which can determine whether a string contains only a number?

Tags: c++, qt

Pretty simply question ... Is there any predefined function in Qt which can determine whether a string contains only a number ? .. with valid entries such as "28" and invalid entries such as " 28", "28 " and "2a8 .... ?

Comment: What do you mean by "a number"?  Should `-` be accepted?  Should `.`?  Should `e`?  Should `Inf` and `NaN`?

Comment: You know your requirements best. For something simple like this, it might be quicker to write your own function than search for an existing function.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you validating user input in a QLineEdit? Or are you trying to convert a string to an integer?

Comment: Well I think I can only accept integer numbers ... So I can't even accept '.' or anything similar ..

Answer (score 5):

Take a look on the [QValidator](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qvalidator.html) and it's subclasses, if you are trying to validate input from the user.

If you are trying to convert the input in a string to a number, take a look in the methods such as toInt from the QString class.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is probably to check if the string contains any whitespace - if it does fail. Then use [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/) and/or [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) to check for a valid number.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

bool HasSpaces( const std::string & s ) {
    return s.find( ' ' ) != std::string::npos;
}

bool IsInt( const std::string & s ) {
    if ( HasSpaces( s ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    char * p;
    strtol( s.c_str(), & p, 10 );   // base 10 numbers 
    return * p == 0;
}


bool IsReal( const std::string & s ) {
    if ( HasSpaces( s ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    char * p;
    strtod( s.c_str(), & p );  
    return * p == 0;
}

int main() {
    assert( IsReal( "1.23" ) );
    assert( IsInt( "1" ) );
    assert( IsInt( "-1" ) );
    assert( IsReal( "-1" ) );
    assert( ! IsInt( "1a" ) );
    assert( ! IsInt( " 1" ) );
}
```

Note the above code on;y works for numbers in the  numeric range of the C++ implementation - it won't work correctly for arbitrarily large integers, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I assume by *number* you mean Integer. You can go this way.

```
int QString::toInt ( bool * ok = 0, int base  = 10 ) const
```

From the documentation,

**If a conversion error occurs, *ok is set to false; otherwise *ok  is set to true.**

So after calling the function, check for the value of `ok`. If it is `true` (i.e if the string can be converted into a number), **then your string has just numbers**.

If your *number* is a double, you can use this function.

```
double QString::toDouble ( bool * ok = 0 ) const
```

More documentation & examples can be seen [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html#toInt)

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

well I agree the simplest way is to convert to a number using toInt() and related functions and checking the boolean parameter, but you can also do something like using qstring::at()  and calling isdigit on the return value like this (looping over the string)

`myString.at(i).isDigit()` this will return true if the character at position i is a number so you can make a simple function that takes a string and returns true if al characters are digits